# Correctly Calling a Complex Fortran Subroutine/Function from Mono C#

Tags: c#, fortran, mono, linear-algebra, dllimport

I have a C# (Unity/Mono on MacOS) application where I need to solve a typical Ax=b matrix optimisation problem with dimensions 3xN. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56519307/690007). I have found that the main method for this is referred to as non-negative least squares (NNLS) and have searched for a pure C# (or similar) implementation but with no luck.

Any solutions are welcome but the closest I have come is the Fortran [implementation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/v0.14.0/scipy/optimize/nnls) used by SciPy's nnls() function with the fortran header:

```
      SUBROUTINE NNLS (A,MDA,M,N,B,X,RNORM,W,ZZ,INDEX,MODE)
C     ------------------------------------------------------------------

      ! Don't leave the calling convention to chance.
      !GCC$ ATTRIBUTES CDECL ::  NNLS

      !DIR$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: NNLS
      !DIR$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS: 'NNLS' :: NNLS

      integer I, II, IP, ITER, ITMAX, IZ, IZ1, IZ2, IZMAX, J, JJ, JZ, L
      integer M, MDA, MODE,N, NPP1, NSETP, RTNKEY
c     integer INDEX(N)  
c     double precision A(MDA,N), B(M), W(N), X(N), ZZ(M)   
      integer INDEX(*)  
      double precision A(MDA,*), B(*), W(*), X(*), ZZ(*)   
      double precision ALPHA, ASAVE, CC, DIFF, DUMMY, FACTOR, RNORM
      double precision SM, SS, T, TEMP, TWO, UNORM, UP, WMAX
      double precision ZERO, ZTEST
      parameter(FACTOR = 0.01d0)
      parameter(TWO = 2.0d0, ZERO = 0.0d0)
C     ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

....

Following a few guides, I have successfully compiled this using gfortran (with a few warnings) to a .so library (Mac DLL equivalent) and have been trying to load it into C# for calling.

```
// C# alias function
[DllImport("Fortran/NNLS.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int NNLS(ref float[,] A, ref int MDA, ref int M, ref int N, ref float[] B, out float[] X, out float RNORM, ref float[] W, ref float[] ZZ, ref int[] INDEX, out int MODE);

// C# call
NNLS(ref A, ref mda, ref m, ref n, ref b, out x, out rnorm, ref w, ref zz, ref index, out mode);
```

The DLL import runs fine but throws 'EntryPointNotFoundException: NNLS'. I have tried a range of changes to naming, binding, calling conventions etc. What am I doing wrong?

The only thing I can think of is that there is currently no module/interface declaration at the top of the fortran file as this causes the compiler to fail on that - not sure how to solve that though.

Comment: You need to find the name by which the function has been exported, and use that. Once you've done that remove `ref` from every array parameter. You also need to allocate each array before the call.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, I will try those. `nm -gU nnls.so` (Mac equivalent to `dumpbin /exports` afaik) shows one entry for each Fortran function: `00000000000010c0 T _nnls_`. Should `_nnls_` therefore  be used as the C# function name or passed as EntryPoint in DLLImport? Also, should `ref` be removed for array arguments in the function definition, call or both?

Comment: Either way works for the name. As for removing ref, you have to do it in both but compiler won't let you get it wrong at the call site.

Comment: I see, good point. Unfortunatley still no luck with 
 `[DllImport(pluginsPath + "Fortran/NNLS.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "_nnls_")]
    public static extern int NNLS(float[,] A, ref int MDA, ref int M, ref int N, float[] B, out float[] X, out float RNORM, float[] W, float[] ZZ, int[] INDEX, out int MODE);`. Throws `EntryPointNotFoundException: _nnls_`.

Comment: Don't really know how things work on platforms other than Windows regarding shared object export naming